# No module named httplib2 but httplib2 installed

Tags: python, desktop-application, httplib2

im installed httplib2 using pip but when i write this code its give me error 
No module named httplib2
why ?
the code

```
import httplib2
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup, SoupStrainer

http = httplib2.Http()
status, response = http.request('http://www.google.com')

for link in BeautifulSoup(response, parseOnlyThese=SoupStrainer('a')):
    if link.has_attr('href'):
    print link['href']
```

Comment: What command did you use to install httplib2? Did it install correctly? Can you open up a Python shell and `import httplib2` there?

Comment: pip install httplip2

Comment: httplip2? You mean httplib2, right? Are you sure you installed the library correctly? Did you install it to the right version of python?

Comment: You can check the package is actually installed by running `pip freeze` and checking the output for the package name.

Comment: thats are the packed
BeautifulSoup==3.2.
httplib2==0.9
pypm==1.4.3
pythonselect==1.3
pywin32==218.3
virtualenv==1.11.6

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try uninstalling and reinstalling using [pip](/questions/tagged/pip):

*Uninstall:*

```
pip uninstall httplib2
```

*Reinstall:*

```
pip install httplib2
```

*List installed packages:*

```
pip freeze
```